# Magento 2 category URL disabled

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.2

On my Magento 2.2.2 store I'm adding new categories. But it seems that on all new, but also the old existing categories. I'm unable to change the URL Key under the 'Seach Engine optimization' tab.

The URL is shown, but it's greyed out and the input field is disabled.

[image]

How can I change the category URL?

Answer (score -1):

You Can Change The Category Url By Dashboard -> Products -> category -> ->Url

SEO Setting are not for changing category url thas why its showing greyed non editable

[See Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaftm.png)

Comment: Your screenshot shows Magento 1 with a Magento 2 skin. It's not actual Magento 2

Comment: I m Using Magento 2.0.8 . for 2.2 the procedure is same ,dont update SEO setting Update the url where u created the category

Comment: Magento 2.2 doesn't have a General information OR URL key tab anymore! The only place where you can edit the URL is under SEO settings. Please check again.